# Unresolved external symbol _IID_IDXGIFactory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, directx, dxgi

I create Console Application in VC++ 2010, and add the following code to it:

```
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <DxErr.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d10.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxerr.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IDXGIFactory* pDXGIFactory;
    CreateDXGIFactory(IID_IDXGIFactory, ( void** )&pDXGIFactory);

    return 0;
}
```

Building this project, I have linker error: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IDXGIFactory

Now I create Console Application with MFC support, and add the same code. The build is successful. What is wrong in the first case? Why MFC project is built successfully, and non-MFC project fails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reference another library, which holds this identifier:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "windowscodecs.lib")
```

[MSDN says its `DXGI.lib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but effectively at least Windows SDK 7.0 has it in a different library.

Comment: The difference is that `dxguid.lib` is DirectX SDK library (as opposed to Windows SDK), and according to MSDN the symbol is already in "core" Windows SDK.

Comment: windowscodecs.lib did help, however didn't solve all my errors.  So, including both that and dxguid.lib, like Alex said, is what it took.  Thanks!

Comment: `IID_ID3D11Device` and `IID_ID3D11DeviceContext` are also found in `dxguid.lib` not in MSDN specified `D3D11.lib`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and In my case referencing
**#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")** solved the issue.