# CreateDXGIFactory function throws Linker Error

Tags: visual-c++, dxgi

I am trying to experiment on the DXGI APIs, and I was creating a console application that enumerates the available Adapters from the Factory Object.

The Code Snippet is as shown below:

```
// pFactory and vecAdapters are initialized as static variables

// Snippet from a static function 
HRESULT result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&pFactory);
if (result == S_OK) {
    UINT i = 0;
    IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter;
    while (pFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &pAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
        vecAdapters.push_back(pAdapter);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

But I am getting a Linker Error as follows:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CreateDXGIFactory@8
```

The headers that I have used are the following:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <vector>
```

Am I missing something?

And thank you so much in advance for helping me out!

Comment: The bottom of the [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-createdxgifactory) tells you what .lib file you need to link.

Comment: Thank you Hans. I can't believe that I didn't see that. So sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Linker Error for CreateDXGIFactory Function](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d58c51e1-b144-4337-9e00-716eb9087812/linker-error-for-createdxgifactory-function?forum=vcgeneral)
- also related [Unresolved external symbol _IID_IDXGIFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911366/unresolved-external-symbol-iid-idxgifactory)

`#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")`

Comment: Note that for various reasons, you should be using ``CreateDXGIFactory1`` or if you don't mind requiring Windows 8.1 or higher, use ``CreateDXGIFactory2``